# Problems with raycasting and onMouseClick to remove a mesh from three.js scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I am trying to remove 4 meshes from my three.js scene when I click on them. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. I am able to change the geometry material but when I try to remove them it doesn't work. Here is my raycasting code below

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onMouseClick( event ) {

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([a, b, c, d]);

    for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {

    if (intersects[ i ].object.geometry.type == "PlaneGeometry") {
            intersects[ i ].object.parent.remove(intersects[ i ].object);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It could be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114224/three-js-raycasting-obj/35725252#35725252

Comment: Tried and didn't work. Thank you though!

Comment: if you are able to change material using raycasting then the issue is not with the posted code.

Comment: The problem I believe is somewhere with my if statement. If you would like to look at the whole code you can see the site here: jacobtruax.info

Answer (score 0):

It might be `intersects[ i ].object.parent` is `null`, so no removing happens.